# org agenda stop strike-through repeated tasks in weekly agenda

Tags: org-agenda

I noticed that when I mark a repeatable task as DONE on the weekly agenda it disappears from the current day, but it shows us strike-through in the following days. How to set faces to have repeatable tasks shows as normal in the following days?

---

EDIT: Sample data file below. After running agenda you will notice that task 6 is shown in following days strike-through.

```
#+STARTUP: overview
#+CATEGORY: Tasks
#+ARCHIVE: ../archive/tasks_archive.org::

* Repeatable
:PROPERTIES:
:CATEGORY: Repeat
:ID:       DD079D5C-9BAD-4525-AB40-9C8F67227387
:END:
** TODO [#B] task 5
:PROPERTIES:
:CREATED: [2020-08-04 Tue]
:STYLE: habit
:ID:       769A16A9-6BA1-4FCC-BAB4-F200F8337948
:LAST_REPEAT: [2020-08-06 Thu 06:51]
:END:
:LOGBOOK:
- State "DONE"       from "TODO"       [2020-08-06 Thu 06:51]
:END:
** TODO [#D] task 6
SCHEDULED: <2020-08-10 Mon .+1d>
:PROPERTIES:
:CREATED: [2020-07-30 Thu]
:STYLE: habit
:LAST_REPEAT: [2020-08-07 Fri 08:26]
:ID:       A666ED14-6497-487F-9E97-A27B67A20A66
:END:
:LOGBOOK:
- State "DONE"       from "TODO"       [2020-08-07 Fri 08:26]
- State "DONE"       from "TODO"       [2020-08-06 Thu 10:51]
- State "DONE"       from "TODO"       [2020-08-05 Wed 09:24]
- State "DONE"       from "TODO"       [2020-08-04 Tue 09:47]
- State "DONE"       from "TODO"       [2020-08-03 Mon 09:39]
- State "DONE"       from "TODO"       [2020-08-02 Sun 11:35]
- State "DONE"       from "TODO"       [2020-08-01 Sat 07:31]
- State "DONE"       from "TODO"       [2020-07-31 Fri 11:24]
- State "DONE"       from "TODO"       [2020-07-30 Thu 10:51]
:END:
** TODO [#C] task 7
SCHEDULED: <2020-08-04 Tue 21:30 .+1d>
:PROPERTIES:
:CREATED: [2020-08-04 Tue]
:STYLE: habit
:ID:       DB420A04-B67E-4110-BEA1-9F8613ED8293
:END:

** TODO [#A] task 8
SCHEDULED: <2020-08-06 Thu .+1d>
```

Agenda config:

```
(setq org-agenda-custom-commands
  '(("d" "Coprehensive agenda"
      ((agenda ""
          ((org-agenda-skip-function
             '(or
                (org-agenda-skip-entry-if 'todo '("WAITING"))
                ))
            (org-agenda-cmp-user-defined 'jarfar/org-agenda-cmp-user-defined-birthday)
            (org-agenda-sorting-strategy '(time-up habit-down todo-state-down priority-down deadline-up scheduled-up effort-down alpha-up))
            (org-agenda-remove-tags nil)
            (ps-number-of-columns 2)
            (ps-landscape-mode 1)
            (org-agenda-files (append org-agenda-files `(,my/org-events-file-path)))))
        )
       )))
```

Comment: Do you have markup on those lines? `+foo+` is rendered that way. If not, post an example: I cannot reproduce it. Try with `emacs -q`: if it works, then something's wonky in your settings. Bisect to figure out what.

Comment: @NickD, thanks.Tthere is no markup on these lines. I added sample data file, I managed to replicate the issue using this data.

Comment: Still cannot reproduce: did you try starting from `emacs -q`?

Comment: If I run emacs with `-q` there will be no configuration available that I try to debug, no agenda files, no agenda commands. I think you can't reproduce it probably because timezone difference. I changed the data of `task 6` so that it should be easier to replicate in following day or two.

Comment: Org mode does not care about timezones  (that's one of its flaws: trying to schedule things across time zones does not work). So I'm seeing exactly the same thing you are seeing. Start with `emacs -q`, open the file, add it to the agenda files with `C-c [` (IOW it will be the only agenda file in the list) and then get an agenda with `M-x org-agenda RET a`.

Comment: What I mentioned above works with *NO* configuration at all on your part, so it is safe. In order to debug configuration problems more conveniently, I have a minimal configuration file that just sets up a few keybindings (e.g `C-c a` for `org-agenda`  - mine also loads org mode from a non-standard place, since I use the upstream bleeding-edge branch, not the version that comes built-in with emacs): it's about 10 lines of code altogether and it is invaluable.  I then start emacs with `emacs -q -l /path/to/minimal.init.el` and debug away. I recommend you do something similar.

Comment: @NickD thanks for your time.

Comment: You are welcome.